# Python and Livy compatible version

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, livy

I have a VM in which livy server is running, and livy version is 0.7.1 and spark version is 2.4.8 and I'm using python 3.7 version
Can I upgrade the my python version to >=3.8, will that be supported in my current livy version?